# Why is Systema used for American secret agents training?

Tags: systema

Following [this](http://www.mixedmartialarts.com/vault/vault/systema-expert-demonstrates-techniques-used-by-the-secret-service) article and the embedded video. We can see that American secret agents are trained to use Systema techniques. What is it? Why not Krav Maga for instance? As can be seen there are some other solutions for the drill with the knife and gun in Krav Maga. What other techniques are trained for secret agents?

Comment: First thing to realize is that there's no official support by the government or the armed forces for any particular martial art. Most branches of the military have their own brand of hand-to-hand combat training. You can find pictures and videos of U.S. military training in Taekwondo, Judo, karate, and even ninjutsu. Who cares? It's just what one small, local group decided to do. It should not imply effectiveness or a preference for any particular martial art.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no known relation between the demonstrator in the video and American "secret agents". This connection is insinuated in the TV show:

> demonstrates how Secret Service agents ***could*** eliminate a threat.
>
> demonstrates how the Secret Service ***can*** up the ante to guard the protect team and spare innocent bystanders

Basically, these are the kinds of techniques that can/should be used. There is no evidence the US Secret Service studies Systema in particular.

Comment: Given who they routinely guard, I would be surprised if there are *any* accurate representations of what/how they train in the public sector.